# How ado.net manages transaction

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net, transactions, msdtc

Guys it seems repetitive question but it is not.

I came across a question which I googled a lot but didn't find any information.

**Query is - "How ado.net manages transaction".**

*Remember query is **NOT** how you will write a code to manage transaction and isolation level.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be more specific or read about transactions in MSDN instead:

- [Local transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x.aspx)
- [Distributed transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973.aspx)